# Cannot get uTest to see my tests

Tags: scala, sbt, scala.js

I'm trying to get uTest to work with ScalaJS and SBT. SBT is compiling the files, and uTest is running, but it simply ignores my tests. Try as I might I cannot find any difference between my code and the tutorial examples.

build.sbt:

```
enablePlugins(ScalaJSPlugin)
name := "Scala.js Stuff"
scalaVersion := "2.11.5" // or any other Scala version >= 2.10.2
scalaJSStage in Global := FastOptStage
libraryDependencies += "com.lihaoyi" %% "utest" % "0.3.0"
testFrameworks += new TestFramework("utest.runner.Framework")
```

src/test/scala/com/mysite/jovian/GeometryTest.scala:

```
package com.mysite.jovian
import utest._
object GeometryTest extends TestSuite {
  def tests = TestSuite { 
      'addPoints {
        val p: Point = new Point(3,4)
        val q: Point = new Point(4,3)
        val expected: Point = new Point(8,8)
        assert(p.plus(q).equals(expected))
        throw new Exception("foo") 
    }
    'fail {
        assert(1==2)
    }
  }
}
```

Output:

```
> reload
[info] Loading project definition from /Users/me/Dropbox (Personal)/mysite/flocks/project
[info] Set current project to Scala.js Stuff (in build file:/Users/me/Dropbox%20(Personal)/mysite/flocks/)
> test
[success] Total time: 1 s, completed Mar 6, 2015 7:01:41 AM
> test-only -- com.mysite.jovian.GeometryTest
[info] Passed: Total 0, Failed 0, Errors 0, Passed 0
[info] No tests to run for test:testOnly
[success] Total time: 1 s, completed Mar 6, 2015 7:01:49 AM
```

If I introduce a syntax error, sbt test does see it:

```
> test
[info] Compiling 1 Scala source to /Users/me/Dropbox (Personal)/mysite/flocks/target/scala-2.11/test-classes...
[error] /Users/me/Dropbox (Personal)/mysite/flocks/src/test/scala/com/mysite/jovian/GeometryTest.scala:21: not found: value blablablablabla
[error]   blablablablabla
[error]   ^
[error] one error found
[error] (test:compile) Compilation failed
[error] Total time: 1 s, completed Mar 6, 2015 7:03:54 AM
```

So it's definitely seeing the code, it just doesn't seem to think that "tests" contains any tests.

Otherwise, in the non-test code, SBT+ScalaJS seems to be working fine...

Thanks for any help, I am mystified.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your mistake lies in the dependency on uTest:

```
libraryDependencies += "com.lihaoyi" %% "utest" % "0.3.0"
```

This is a JVM dependency. To use the Scala.js-enabled dependency, use `%%%` instead of `%%`, like this:

```
libraryDependencies += "com.lihaoyi" %%% "utest" % "0.3.0"
```

Additionally, you probably want this dependency only in the Test configuration, so add `% "test"` a the end:

```
libraryDependencies += "com.lihaoyi" %%% "utest" % "0.3.0" % "test"
```

Comment: Thanks, that worked great! (If I wasn't brand new here and were allowed to, I would upvote)

Comment: Oh my god, I wish I had seen this answer one hour ago! This should really be pointed out more explicitly in the documentation...