# cannot get uTest to run tests

Tags: scala, sbt, scala.js, utest

I am following the [Basic Tutorial](http://www.scala-js.org/tutorial/basic/) over at Scala.JS. I've also followed [Cannot get uTest to see my tests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28898445/cannot-get-utest-to-see-my-tests)

I update my build.sbt to have the following:

```
testFrameworks += new TestFramework("utest.runner.Framework")
libraryDependencies += "com.lihaoyi" %%% "utest" % "0.3.0" % "test"
```

I have created

> src/test/scala/tutorial/webapp/TutorialTest.scala

```
package tutorial.webapp

import utest._
import org.scalajs.jquery.jQuery

object TutorialTest extends TestSuite {

  // Initialize App
  TutorialApp.setupUI()

  def tests = TestSuite {
    'HelloWorld {
      assert(jQuery("p:contains('Hello World')").length == 1)
    }
  }
}
```

I reload sbt, then type 'test', but I always get the following error:

> [error] MyProject/src/main/scala/tutorial/webapp/TutorialTest.scala:3:
>   not found: object utest [error] import utest._

If I remove the tail {% "test"} from my build.sbt, I'm able to run the 'test' command from sbt but it doesn't pick up my tests.

I hope I'm making sense here, this error has stumped me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error message shows that you have TutorialTest.scala under `src/main`. It should be under `src/test`. (Perhaps you accidentally put it in both places?)

Test dependencies (such as utest) are only on the classpath when compiling test sources — hence the error.

Comment: Perfect! I must've missed the part of the tutorial that told me to create the file under src/test and *not* src/main :-s